# Flexibility and customization in Tapestry Framework

Tags: tapestry

I was doing some research about different Java Web MVC frameworks for my new website and stumbled upon Tapestry 5.3.2. I was wondering about the flexibility and customization framework provides. Lets say if I am using

```
beaneditform
```

which automatically generates a form with the fields of object it takes, something like -

```
First name [    ]  
Last name [   ]  
Street1 [    ]  
City [    ]  
State [    ]
```

But lets say if I want to display all these fields in the same line like following, then what I have to do -

```
First name [    ] Last name [    ] Street1 [    ] City [    ] State [    ]
```

Moreover I want to apply my own css to all these text boxes. And my own javascript validations using jquery.

Same question applies to other component like

```
grid
```

How do I change look and feel of the grid generated by the framework.

I also wanted to know whether its a right framework for social networking kind of website where traffic will be very high and scalability and performance will be major concerns.

Thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Much of what you just described can be done using custom CSS.  Render your BeanEditForm, view the source, and then see about creating CSS to give it the layout you want. Further, there's a BeanEditForm parameter for controlling the CSS class name of the outermost  element.

However, BeanEditForm and Grid are intended as scaffolding, to provide a quick, provisional UI early in the project, but also ripped out in favor of custom forms by the time you get to production.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the component reference docs, there are good samples in it.
As you can see, you can customize and override every single property, rearrange them or add custom properties. This applies to both components.

http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/BeanEditForm.html